# SQL Server : SUM of column with alphanumeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when, alphanumeric

I want to get the sum of a column that is alphanumeric. I want to add numeric values and return column values if not numeric. What I did is a added a `CASE WHEN` that looks like this

```
CASE 
   WHEN intAllocatedResourceperDivision NOT IN ('CL', 'HS', 'HV', 'ML', 'SL', 'VL', 'HC', 'S', '*') 
      THEN CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(intAllocatedResourceperDivision AS DECIMAL), 0.00)) AS NVARCHAR(250)) 
      ELSE intAllocatedResourceperDivision 
END intAllocatedResourceperDivision
```

So I assume that all numeric values will be added and if values is in `('CL', 'HS', 'HV', 'ML', 'SL', 'VL', 'HC', 'S', '*')` it will be returned as is.

But I'm getting

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your SUM aggregation is out of place. You only sum if the condition in the case statement is true. Try this:

```
SUM(case when intAllocatedResourceperDivision NOT IN ('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*') THEN intAllocatedResourceperDivision else 0 end)
```

In case you don't know the exact potential combination of non numeric values, you can use the `ISNUMERIC` function (assuming you're using SQL Server) to test whether or not the value is a number and assign a 0 if it's not, aggregating the final result.

```
SUM(case when ISNUMERIC(intAllocatedResourceperDivision) = 1 then intAllocatedResourceperDivision else 0 end)
```

To aggregate the numerical values and also keep non-numerical, you can use a union query as such:

```
select
    cast(SUM(cast(intAllocatedResourceperDivision as decimal(18,2))) as varchar)
from
    YOUR_TABLE
where
    ISNUMERIC(intAllocatedResourceperDivision) = 1

UNION ALL

select
    intAllocatedResourceperDivision
from
    YOUR_TABLE
where
    ISNUMERIC(intAllocatedResourceperDivision) = 0
```

Comment: want to return as is value if not numeric meaning return ('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*') is that possibble

Comment: It is possible with a different approach. You have to split the data into 2 different datasets (numerical and non-numerical), perform the aggregation and then combine both datasets together once again. I have updated my answer to also reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server syntax.  I would recommend using `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL, intAllocatedResourceperDivision) as intAllocatedResourceperDivision
```

Comment: want to return as is value if not numeric meaning return `('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*')` is that possibble

Comment: @guradio . . . I don't understand the logic.  Do you want a number or a string as the return value?  Sample data and desired results in the question would help.

Comment: I want the result to be sum of numeric if value is numeric if not numeric then return the current value(which us either of the values in the ( `('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*')` )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 'CL' as intAllocatedResourceperDivision into #tmp
union select 'HS'union select 'HV'union select 'ML'union select 'SL'union select 'VL'union select 'HC'union select 'S'union select '*'union select '1'union select '4'

select CAST(SUM(ISNULL(CAST(intAllocatedResourceperDivision AS DECIMAL),0.00)) AS nvarchar(250)) as intAllocatedResourceperDivision
from #tmp where intAllocatedResourceperDivision NOT IN ('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*')
union 
select intAllocatedResourceperDivision
from #tmp where intAllocatedResourceperDivision IN ('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*')
```

Comment: want to return as is value if not numeric meaning return ('CL','HS','HV','ML','SL','VL','HC','S','*') is that possibble